# Inverse of a lower triangular Toeplitz matrix vs. the matrix size

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, inverse, gamma-function, toeplitz-matrices

> Find the inverse of the following lower triangular Toeplitz matrix
>
> $$\mathbf{A}_{M\times M}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
> 1\\
> -a_{1} & 1\\
> -a_{2} & -a_{1} & 1\\
> \vdots &  &  & \ddots\\
> -a_{M-1} & \cdots & -a_{2} & -a_{1} & 1
> \end{array}\right],
> $$
>
> where $$a_i=\frac{c\Gamma(i-c)}{\Gamma(i+1)\Gamma(1-c)}$$ and $c\in(0,1)$ is a real constant.

I hope to find the closed-form expression of $\Vert \mathbf{A} ^{-1} \Vert_1$, where $\Vert\cdot\Vert_1$ represents the $L_1$ induced norm. (Actually, in this case, it is the summation of the first column of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$.)   And if possible, I hope to find how the matrix size $M$ affects the value of $\Vert \mathbf{A} ^{-1} \Vert_1$, i.e., 
$$
f(M)=\Vert \mathbf{A}_{M\times M} ^{-1} \Vert_1.
$$
Even a tight approximation or bounds are acceptable.

There are some properties of $\{a_i\}$, for example, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=1$. But by now I haven't had ideas how to solve it. I appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to start by using a "closed" form formula for the inverse of $A$. Set $A=I-N$, where $N$ is strict lower triangular ($a$'s with $+$ signs), then
$$
A^{-1}=(I-N)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}N^i.
$$
So if $\|A^{-1}\|_1=\|A^{-1}e_1\|_1$ (which is true provided that $a$'s are non-negative as $A^{-1}$ is Toeplitz as well), then you would need to evaluate the terms $N^{-1}e_1$.

Another possible hint: Partition $A$ as
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{A}&\\a^T&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\tilde{A}$ is the leading principal $(M-1)\times(M-1)$ sub-matrix  of $A$
and $a^T=[-a_{M-1},\ldots,-a_1]$.
The inverse can be written explicitly as
$$
A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{A}^{-1} & 0 \\ -a^T\tilde{A}^{-1} & 1\end{bmatrix},
$$
so
$$
A^{-1}e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}\tilde{A}^{-1}e_1 \\ -a^T\tilde{A}^{-1}e_1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence if $x_i$ is the $i$th component of $A^{-1}e_1$ (with $x_1=1$), there is a recursion for $x_M$ in the form
$$
x_M=\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}a_{M-i}x_i.
$$

Comment: Hi @Pavel Jiranek, thanks so much for your reply. For the first part of your answer, I can understand, and I have tried before. But I cannot get the result, since the power of $N$ is also complicated. However, I am not clear your last sentence. What is $e_1$ here? What's $N^{-1}e_1$ stands for? I think the inverse of $N$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Chang $e_1=[1,0,\ldots,0]^T$. So $A^{-1}e_1$ is the first column of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I think your point is $\Vert \mathbf{A}^{-1} \Vert_1 = \mathbf{A}^{-1}e_1 = \sum_{i=0}^{M-1}N^i e_1$. Is it correct? Now the problem is that even I do so, I cannot get clear expression of $N^i$. I hope the expression of $a_i$ could help...

Comment: @Chang Yes, I've meant $\|A^{-1}\|_1=\|A^{-1}e_1\|_1=\|\sum_{i=0}^{M-1}N^ie_1\|_1$. Maybe also you could get some reasonable bound by using the triangle inequality in the last term.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel Jiranek. You are so nice. The inverse of the lower triangular Toeplitz matrix has the recursion form, exactly as what you have written. You can have a look at the link: http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/research/papers/TRENCH_TN_6.PDF But still, I need to think about how to solve it. Thanks.